# WSL Kubuntu - How to launch Kubuntu (and Gnome) in WSL

Tags: gnome, scripts, kubuntu, kde, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed WSL with Ubuntu, and it is able to launch XFCE graphical environment, by a batch script file with these commands:

```
start /B x410.exe /desktop
ubuntu2004.exe run "if [ -z \"$(pidof xfce4-session)\" ]; then export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0; xfce4-session; pkill '(gpg|ssh)-agent'; fi;"
```

**Would it be possible a batch scrit file to launch Ubuntu WSL with Gnome or Kde?**

The following link has a batch file for KDE, but it is for the Fedora distribution: [Windows 10 + WSL2 + Fedora Remix + KDE + X410](https://rodrigolira.eti.br/windows-10-wsl2-fedora-remix-kde-x410/)

Observation: I'm newbie and not a professional.

thanks for you attention.